# Cannot Find an Existing File

Tags: c#, list, file

This is code I have:

```
File.WriteAllText("combo_format.txt",File.ReadAllText("combo.txt").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine,""));
File.WriteAllText("combo_format.txt", File.ReadAllText("combo_format.txt").Replace("TEST", System.Environment.NewLine));
List<string> combo = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("combo_format.txt"));
```

The file combo_format doesnt exist before I run the programm. As you can see, I'm creating the file combo_format and the store its text into a list. However I get this error while executing the last line:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException :
> 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\Will\source\repos\txt sorter\txt sorter\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\combo_format'.'

If someone could help me, thank you.

Comment: You might need to deal with the space in the filename

Comment: I don't think the code you've provided would produce that error - notice how the error message doesn't have ".txt" at the end of the file that it can't find. (Is there any reason why you're writing a file only to read it again in the first place though? Why not just do all the transformation in memory, and write the file *once*?)

Comment: The problem was that the file couldn't create properly bcs the program was "running to fast". Anyway ty.